# Strange behaviour with range.toString()

Tags: javascript, firefox, range

I want to get back the text that I select in an element using the Range object provided by Mozilla's flavour of javascript.

So I do this:

```
//assume that I'm only using Firefox, and there is just one selection
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var rangeText = range.toString();
```

This works OK when the html of the selected text doesn't have any newlines In other words, if I have the following html:

```
<div>One. Two. Three. Four. Five.</div>
```

and I select **Two. Three. Four.**, then everything is fine.

On the other hand, if I have

```
<div>
One.
Two.
Three.
Four.
Five.
</div>
```

and I select **Two. Three. Four.** as before, there are newlines introduced into the result returned from Range.toString(); the newlines are after **Two.**, **Three.**, and **Four.**

Obviously, when displayed in the browser, both html fragments are identical. Is there a way I can ensure that the same text is returned without newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I used part of the answer from Tim Down in the end:

```
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  var range2 = range.cloneRange();

  //do some stuff with range2...

  var rangeText, range2Text;

  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  rangeText = sel.toString();

  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range2);
  range2Text = sel.toString();
```

Comment: That will do what you want, but you should make sure you restore the selection to whatever it started as at the end so as not to confuse the user.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
range.toString().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
```

Comment: `\s` is sufficient as it matches `[\f\n\r\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029]`. See http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Comment: This almost worked, but I found that there were spaces that were being inserted between the '<div>' and the 'One' that it couldn't get rid of, since it could only reduce them to a single space. In other words, it still wasn't getting me the exact text between the div tags.

Comment: I've edited the answer to trim whitespace from the ends of the string.