# UIWebview get range of selected text and save for later use

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I got the range of a selected text from UIWebView using the following java script function :

```
function getRangeForSelectedText() {
    var selection = window.getSelection(); 
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0); 
}
```

I have to save this range for later use (I want to use this range to highlight the text when the user loads the doc at a later time). How can i save a java script object(range) in objective C?

Is there any other method to hightlight a text in a UIWebview other than giving the range?

Answer (score 0):

see that post 
http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

and that [How to call Objective-C from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript)

you can send some string to your UIWebView using script

```
function sendURLToUIWebView(url) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", url);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
 }
```

your url should has specific schem f.e. `myappcomand://`

and you can handle it with `UIWebViewDelegate` method (set some object as delegate of UIWebView, f.e. some UIViewController)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
 BOOL shouldLoad = YES;
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"myappcomand"]) {
         shouldLoad = NO;
         // parse url string "request.URL" and extract your parameters to store them
    }
return shouldLoad;
}
```

your javascript functions

```
function sendURLToUIWebView(url) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", url);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
 }

function getRangeForSelectedText() {
    var selection = window.getSelection(); 
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var url = "myappcomand://" + "range=" + range; // you should convert range to string 
    sendURLToUIWebView(url);
}
```

**Update:**

range to string

```
range.toString().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
```

or just `var rangeText = window.getSelection().toString();`

see [Strange behaviour with range.toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586231/strange-behaviour-with-range-tostring)

Comment: But my problem is how i can covert range object into a string. Range object consists of start container , end container, start offset,end offset. I can convert start offset and end offset into string because they are integers. But start container and end container are node objects.

Comment: @PriyankaV what streeng do you have when you use range.toString() ?

Comment: range.toString().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') this is giving the selected text. But i dont need selected text

Comment: can you convert to string some one from those variables? var startNode = range.startContainer, endNode = range.endContainer; endNode.length; range.startOffset;

Comment: i converted range.startOffset and range.endOffset to string and send back to objective c as a string:                 function f() {
    var txt = window.getSelection();
    var anchorNodeProp = txt.anchorNode;   //get the node object        
    return (txt.anchorOffset + '|' + txt.anchorNode.textContent + '|' + txt.focusOffset + '|' + txt.focusNode.textContent);
}                                                                    NSString *rangeObject = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"f()"];     But what can i do with that start container object.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Instead of getting selected range, i just highlighted the selected text using below function in js and fetch full text in UIWebView and replaced that in sqlite.

JS code:

```
function highlight() {

    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.appendChild(selectionContents);
        span.setAttribute("class","uiWebviewHighlight");
        span.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(237,191,245)";
        span.style.color = "black";
        range.insertNode(span);
    } 
}
```

Objective C:

```
- (void) highlightText
{
    NSString *highlightFunction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"highlight()"];
    [detailedWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:startSearch];
    NSString *highlightedString = [detailedWebView 
                         stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
}
```

Simply replace old html string with highlightedString.